# Как убрать с body.innerHTML возврат каретки ↵ (стрелку клавиши Ентер)

Tags: javascript

В body есть текст например:

```
<body>
Какой то текст
</body>
```

Когда беру его Джаваскриптом и разбиваю на отдельные слова например:

```
<script>
var bodyHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
var bodyHTML = bodyHTML.split(' ');
console.log(bodyHTML);
</script>
```

то в консоли вижу массив

```
["↵Какой", "то", "текст↵↵"]
```

Т.е. перед первым словом стоит стрелка клавиши Ентер ↵ и две такие же стрелки после последнего слова. Как убрать их Джаваскриптом, не меняя хтмл-код body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже нашел, вот так можно:

```
bodyHTML = bodyHTML.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант - использовать свойства [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) или [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
var bodyHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText;

var bodyHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent;
```

```js
var b = document.body;
var ih = b.innerHTML.split(' ').filter(function(el){return el.length<5 && el.length>0});
var it = b.innerText.split(' ').filter(function(el){return el.length<5 && el.length>0});
var tc = b.textContent.split(' ').filter(function(el){return el.length<5 && el.length>0});

document.write(
  '<br/>innerHTML: ' + JSON.stringify(ih),
  '<br/>innerText: ' +JSON.stringify(it),
  '<br/>textContent: ' +JSON.stringify(tc)
);
```

```html
asds gasd sgdf gsdf g
```

Comment: innerText — да, textContent — не помогает

Comment: @stckvrw, похоже да, добавил пример что выводит каждая функция. что характерно - вывод разный для всех трех